# An elegant and stylish letter (or letters) using mtpro2

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, mtpro, newtx

Reading Walter Schmidt's guide `.pdf` of 2008/1/23 related to Math Time Professional II fonts with LaTeX, alias `mtpro2`, I have viewed the site of the very good user and young colleague [**Tobi**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918/tobi) to which I give my heartfelt congratulations for your skill that he have acquired after that I have 
visited your profile.

I liked the fonts used especially the `k` indicated in the following link: https://tobiw.de/en/gallery#oscillations-and-waves&gid=3&pid=6

[image]

where I have made a small screenshot. It seems that the character is written with a fountain pen. Excellent. I had a old file `.tex` with another similar `k`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Taking k from fouriernc font
\DeclareFontEncoding{FML}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareSymbolFont{fourierletters}{FML}{fncmi}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{fourierletters}{bold}{FML}{fncmi}{b}{it}
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{k}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`k}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mst@k}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{`k}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$k$
\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

Is there a way to have a similar `k` that fits better itself with Times New Roman (`newtxtext`) but does not compromise my long code structure?

Thank you very much to all for your collaboration.

**ADDENDUM:**
In the opinion of the experts at the graphics site,
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/127153/technical-name-of-a-particular-fountain-pen-font 
the font could be Adobe® Garamond Pro Italic:

[image]

At this point is it possible to modify my MWE (with the same technique) to have a similar `k`, with a free `LaTeX` font that compiles with `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the `k` from EBGaramond (or its math companion to be precise). Minimal document showing that only `$k$` is affected so you should be able to combine this with whatever other font-setup you have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{ebgletters}{OML}{EBGaramond-Maths}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{k}{\mathalpha}{ebgletters}{`k}

\begin{document}
k\textit{k} $k = x + 1$
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great and wonderful !!!!!!!!!!!! When I write on the blackboard I often use the English k. But I'm also getting used to the Italian k :-) "Grazie di cuoreeeeee".